# How to stop collecting telemetry once started in Windows Store app?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I've started looking at adding Azure Application Insights to my app. The documentation and the SDK seems to be a bit sparse ...

I've added a call to Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync and the data is being successfully reported to the Azure Portal.

However, I want to provide a setting in the app so that the user can turn collection on and off. Is there a way of stopping collection or can I only "not start" collection? In other words, if the user changes the setting value, can I react to it straight away or just when the app starts up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this:

To dynamically stop and start the collection and transmission of telemetry:

```cs
using  Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = true;
```

To disable selected standard collectors - for example,

- performance counters
- HTTP requests
- dependencies

Delete or comment out the relevant lines in `ApplicationInsights.config`. You could do this, for example, if you want to send your own **TrackRequest** data.

**Taken from App Insights [Documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/):**